# Beginner Java Question - "Breakout" game. What's my next step?

Tags: java

This is my first post on SO!

I've on my own been working a few weeks through Stanford's "Programming Methodology" class which is an intro to programming with java. I've been doing all the programs so far with little difficulty, researching what I needed with minimal difficulty.

Right now, all I have are a set of bricks, and a ball that I was able to get to bounce off the walls. Currently the ball doesn't do anything but bounce around in the canvas and just passes through the bricks.
There are lots of steps involved, the other ones I am pretty sure I can take care of. The ones I am having a hard time with are...

1) Get the ball to bounce off the bricks.
2) Get the bricks to disappear when the ball bounces off them.

some resources I've been using -
[Using the ACM Graphics Package](http://jtf.acm.org/tutorial/UsingTheGraphicsPackage.html)
[Stanford PDF with the assignment guidelines](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/19-assignment-3-breakout.pdf)

I guess my question is. What do I need to understand in order to be able to solve the problems I listed above. In one of the lectures, the professor talks about using "getElementAt()" But I don't really understand how that method works or how I can use it to get my ball to bounce off the bricks and then after, make them disappear.

Code I wrote so far -

```
/*
 * File: Breakout.java
 * -------------------
 * Name: Sandi
 * Section Leader: I'm learning this online
 *
 * This file will eventually implement the game of Breakout.
 */

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Breakout extends GraphicsProgram {

    /** Width and height of application window in pixels */
    public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 600;

    /** Dimensions of game board (usually the same) */
    private static final int WIDTH = APPLICATION_WIDTH;
    private static final int HEIGHT = APPLICATION_HEIGHT;

    /** Dimensions of the paddle */
    private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 10;

    /** Offset of the paddle up from the bottom */
    private static final int PADDLE_Y_OFFSET = 30;

    /** Number of bricks per row */
    private static final int NBRICKS_PER_ROW = 10;

    /** Number of rows of bricks */
    private static final int NBRICK_ROWS = 10;

    /** Separation between bricks */
    private static final int BRICK_SEP = 4;

    /** Width of a brick */
    private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = (WIDTH - (NBRICKS_PER_ROW - 1)
            * BRICK_SEP)
            / NBRICKS_PER_ROW;

    /** Height of a brick */
    private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 8;

    /** Radius of the ball in pixels */
    private static final int BALL_RADIUS = 10;

    /** Offset of the top brick row from the top */
    private static final int BRICK_Y_OFFSET = 70;

    /** Number of turns */
    private static final int NTURNS = 3;

    /* Method: run() */
    /** Runs the Breakout program. */

    public void run() {
        addBricks();
        addBall();

        //velocity of the ball's x and y
        ballVX = 1;
        ballVY = 2;

        while (true) {
            moveBall();
            pause(10);
        }
    }

    private void addBricks() {
        int startY = BRICK_Y_OFFSET;
        GRect brick;

        for (int i = 0; i < NBRICK_ROWS; i++) {

            int startX = BRICK_SEP;

            for (int j = 0; j < NBRICKS_PER_ROW; j++) {
                brick = new GRect(startX, startY, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                add(brick);

                colorBricks(brick, Color.RED, 0, 1);
                colorBricks(brick, Color.ORANGE, 2, 3);
                colorBricks(brick, Color.YELLOW, 4, 5);
                colorBricks(brick, Color.GREEN, 6, 7);
                colorBricks(brick, Color.CYAN, 8, 9);

                startX += BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP;
            }

            startY += BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP;
        }
    }

    private void colorBricks(GRect brick, Color color, int fromRowNumber,
            int toRowNumber) {
        //this will make it so that if the bricks are between two y coordinates
        //then the method will set it to a certain color and color it.
        if (brick.getY() >= BRICK_Y_OFFSET + fromRowNumber
                * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP)
                && brick.getY() <= BRICK_Y_OFFSET + toRowNumber
                        * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP)) {
            brick.setColor(color);
            brick.setFilled(true);
        }
    }

    private void addBall() {
        ball = new GOval(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, BALL_RADIUS,
                BALL_RADIUS);
        ball.setFilled(true);
        add(ball);
    }

    private void moveBall() {
        double borderX = ball.getX();
        double borderY = ball.getY();

        if (borderX == 0 || borderX == getWidth() - BALL_RADIUS) {
            ballVX = -ballVX;
        }
        if (borderY == 0 || borderY == getHeight() - BALL_RADIUS) {
            ballVY = -ballVY;
        }

        ball.move(ballVX, ballVY);
    }

    private GOval ball;
    private double ballVX;
    private double ballVY;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `getElementAt()` would likely be used for hit detection... You can check every point at the perimeter of your ball to see if it's hit a brick.

Comment: You might want to try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

There are of course many things that could be done to enhance your program. But to solve your next problem I think you have to understand a little bit of the "magic" of the classes you are depend on.

I havn't studied your API in depth, but it looks like your call `add(brick);` adds your brick to an array/collection internally stored in `GraphicsProgram` (if you can get the source code of the classes you depend on it might be helpfull to read and understand the code). You can access the objects you have added later on with `getElementAt`. So if you add a brick at the location `(10,20)` and later call `getElementAt(10,20)` it should return this brick.

You should modify your `moveBall` method to check if the new position of the ball would contain a brick and, if so, act accordingly. Something like this:

```
private void moveBall() {
    double borderX = ball.getX();
    double borderY = ball.getY();

    GRect brick = getElementAt(borderX, borderY);
    if (brick != null) {
        doSomethingWithBall();
    } else {
        if (borderX == 0 || borderX == getWidth() - BALL_RADIUS) {
            ballVX = -ballVX;
        }
        if (borderY == 0 || borderY == getHeight() - BALL_RADIUS) {
            ballVY = -ballVY;
        }
    }

    ball.move(ballVX, ballVY);
}
```

You might have to fiddle a little bit with the values you pass into `getElementAt` and what exactly you do when you find a brick. You have to take into account that the bricks are not points but have a height and a width, the ball is moving and not a point, too ...

**Edit:** Your ball is added to the collection, too. So it might be possible that the ball is returned instead of a brick. You should not pass the actual position of your ball to the `getElementAt` method but an value where the ball is after it moves half the ball radius when there is no brick in the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
private GObject getCollidingObject() {
    double x = ball.getX(), y = ball.getY();
    if (getElementAt(x, y) != null) { return getElementAt(x, y); }
    else if (getElementAt(x, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2) != null) { 
        return getElementAt(x, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2); }
    else if (getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2) != null) {
        return getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y + BALL_RADIUS * 2); }
    else if (getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y) != null) {
        return getElementAt(x + BALL_RADIUS * 2, y); }
        else { return null; }
}
```

... these two methods works perfectly together ...

```
private void elementsCollisions() {
     GObject collider = getCollidingObject();
     if (collider == paddle) { 
         vy = -vy; 
     }
     else if (collider != null) { 
         remove(collider); 
         vy = -vy;
}
```

`getElementAt(x, y)` - returns object at the specified point. Decompose problem as much as possible if you can't solve fast.

Answer (score 0):

**Index the bricks in a way that you can easily check if a brick exists at a certain coordinate.**

When you create a brick, you add it to the container, and then you lose it.  You don't have a reference to it going forward that you can use to compare to the current ball location.

Based on your design, I believe you should do this through a 2-dimensional array.  When you create the bricks, also put the `GRect` object in a 2-dimensional array.  One dimension should be the row, and the other the column.  Then you will be able to access these bricks by x and y coordinate using this array.  (This is what you will need to do to detect a bounce.)

When the ball moves, the same way that you detect it bouncing off walls, check if the ball's position makes it border a spot where a brick could be.  If it does, from any direction, then check if the brick is actually there by looking at your array.  If there is a brick there, bounce the ball and remove the brick.  Also be sure to set that location in the array to be `null` to indicate that the brick is gone.

Then you also have your victory condition... when all of the elements of the array have been set to null.

Comment: By the way, your code to detect bounces off the walls (and therefore off the bricks) is flawed.  If you use non-whole number values for `ballVX` or `ballVY`, your ball will go right through one of the sides without bouncing off it.  You will need to check if the X or Y movement of the ball would cause it to intersect the edge of the screen or a brick, and then determine which it will hit first, then change its direction vector appropriately.  I hope you did well in geometry!